# Объединение двух SQL-запросов к одной таблице (первый с DISTINCT, второй с MIN)

Tags: mysql

Есть товары (`item_id`).
Каждый товар продается одним конкретным продавцом (`user_id`).
Есть данные о доходах от продажи этих товаров, полученные в разные дни (`revenue, report_date`).
Для каждого `item_id` существует много разных пар `(revenue, report_date)`.
И всё это лежит в одной таблице: `(str_id*, item_id, user_id, revenue, report_date)`.

Нужно получить таблицу из двух столбцов:
- в первом столбце - все товары данного продавца в бесповторном упорядоченном виде
(т.е. `SELECT DISTINCT item_id FROM table WHERE user_id = %user_id% ORDER BY item_id ASC`),
- во втором - для каждого товара соответствующая ему самая ранняя отчетная дата
(т.е. `SELECT MIN(report_date) FROM table WHERE item_id = %item_id%`).

Возможно ли объединить эти два запроса в один? То есть каждое конкретное значение `item_id`, полученное при выполнении первого запроса, как-то подставлять во второй запрос?

(Понятно, что с помощью внешнего языка программирования, например PHP, можно сначала выполнить первый запрос, потом для каждого из полученных значений `item_id` выполнить второй запрос и получить что надо, но мне так делать не хочется, поскольку это потребует выполнения очень большого количества запросов.)

Comment: *Возможно ли объединить эти два запроса в один?* Да запросто. Группировка по продавцу и товару, минимум по дате.

Answer (score 0):

Точно :)

```
SELECT item_id, MIN(report_date) AS first_date, revenue  
FROM table  
WHERE user_id = %user_id%  
GROUP BY item_id  
ORDER BY first_date ASC, item_id ASC
```

`DISTINCT` не нужен, т.к. применяется агрегатная функция (в данном случае `MIN`).